# cohomology ring of grassmannian

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, grassmannian

Let $G_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the grassmannian consisting of all $k$-subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

How to compute the cohomology ring

$$H^*(G_k(\mathbb{R}^n);\mathbb{Z})$$

and what is the result?

Comment: [This helps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian#Schubert_cells) for $n$ even.

Comment: most attempts that I know use a particular CW structure. If I remember right, you can find it for instance in Milnor & Stasheff's book about characteristic classes.

Comment: Is the algebraic geometry tag appropriate here? Sure the Grassmannian is cut out by polynomials, but this question is dealing with the real topology.